# Removing Win8 Preview from boot sequence

Tags: windows-8

A while back I installed the preview and then thought I successfully deleted it.  However, on every reboot I get an error that there is a missing file for Win8.  Then if I hit the F9 key I can then boot into Vista w/o any problem.

Is some remnant of Win8 in my boot record?  can I make it go away so I boot directly inot Vista?

Answer (score 0):

Inside Windows Vista, run `msconfig.exe`, go under the `boot` tab and delete the Windows 8 entry.

[image]